# amCharts 5: Is is possible to rotate axes tick labels?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

Is is possible to rotate axes tick labels in amCharts 5? E.g.

[image]

I am unable to find this mentioned anywhere in the new amCharts 5 documentation. This was [possible in amCharts 4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/wrapping-and-truncating-axis-labels/#Auto_rotating_labels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the `rotation` property on the relevant axis-renderer's `labels.template`, eg:

```js
//...
const xAxisRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {});

xAxisRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
  rotation: -45,
});

const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: xAxisRenderer ,
    categoryField: 'category-name-here',
  })
);
//...
```

**Found via:** [amCharts 5 demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/zYzgyWd)